# Anonymous access not allowed

Tags: permissions, anonymous-authentication

I have a web application that i created //myapp.port# on my web server

I have enabled anonymous access according to this link:

http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html

Central Admin -> Manage web application -> Authentication Providers -> Default -> Enable Anonymous users (checked)

Went into the web app under Site Permissions and set Anonymous access to: "Entire Web Site"

I have extended my application onto Port 80 so that it is browsable publically by an ip address. This extended site in "Internet Zone" has been set to allow anonymous users.

In IIS under "Authentication Rules" and "Authorization" I have allowed anonymous users.

Everytime I browse to the site, it still asks for credentials.

Any ideas why? or is there something I missed?

Comment: Can other users get there or have you tried a different machine? Seems like you covered everything so just validating its not the current machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed the issue after some time.

I had an application page popping up on my homepage, and I had to change the inherited class for the page from 'LayoutsPageBase' to 'UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase' override the AllowAnonymousAccess property shown below

```
    public partial class className : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
   {

    protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```